# Как добавить NavController в Fragment

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Выскакивает ошибка при добавлении `NavController` в `Fragment`е

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vmining.sport, PID: 14450
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
    at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3304)
    at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
    at com.vmining.sport.HomeFreeVip.onCreateView(HomeFreeVip.java:26)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3337)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7565)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Код `Fragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_free_vip_fragment, container, false);


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationVieww);
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireContext(),  R.id.fragmentt);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

    return rootView;
}
```

Код `Fragment` xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFreeVip">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationVieww"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/vip_botton_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentt"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/vip_my_nav" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Или NavController можно использовать только в `Activity`? Всем спасибо!)

Comment: Или NavController можно использовать только в Activity? - Да

Comment: @Ilnar Ответ внизу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFreeVip">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/vip_botton_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код Fragment:

```
    public class HomeFreeVip extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_free_vip_fragment, container, false);


        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new AnalyticsFragment()).commit();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = 
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.freeFragment:
                            selectedFragment = new FreeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.vipFragment:
                            selectedFragment = new VipFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
    ;
    
    
}
```